# Word 2016: Is there a way to make all first line paragraph indentations uniform throughout doc?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, indentation

I'm editing a rather long document that has various spacing for first line indentation. I need to standardize it.

Is there a way to do that without doing it manually for every single paragraph?

Comment: Select the whole document and edit indentation??

Answer (score 1):

You can change the first line indentation by highlighting the entire document and using **Paragraph** settings.

---

1. Highlight the entire document with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. Right click the text and select **Paragraph**.

[image: Paragraph menu option]

3. Open the **Indents and Spacing** tab.

[image: Indents and spacing tab]

4. Under **Indentation**, set **Special** to **First Line** and set the indentation using the **By** option.

[image: First line spacing options]

Comment: Do you know of any way to keep first paragraphs "normal" and apply this indented formatting only to following paragraphs?

Answer (score -1):

Normally in Word, your paragraphs should all be of a certain *style* (maybe 'Normal', maybe some other custom name).
If you adjust that style, they are all adjusted - that's the idea of using *styles*.

It makes little sense to find a workaround to avoid one of the core functionalities of Word, and then make it behave as if it was used anyway.
So the strong recommendation is to change all your text (that you'd like to be affected) to a specific style, and then adjust that style.

Comment: It may help to explain the process for adjusting font styles, since the asker may not know how.